# Button does not respond in the media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have got a button that redirects you to a hype-link i have tried so hard to debug but i don't seem to find the bugs.It works fine on the full size screen but it is not clickable on the media query i applied.

*1.* First i tried to comment out the hamburg menu because i copied it from some video then but it didn't seem to be the problem.
*2.* Then i tried to change from max-width to min-width it also didn't work.
*3.* I also tried using the z-index on the button hoping it gets on the front but also didn't work.
Checkout the entire website at https://spectrumsdl.com . Nothing seems clickable when in the media query view port.

```css
@media(max-width:650px) {
  * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: mon reg;
    transition: ease-in-out .8s;
  }
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    /* background:wheat; */
  }
  .nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    /* background-color: white; */
    top: -900px;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: top 0.8s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  .right {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style-type: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .nav ul li :hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: .3s;
    color: var(--textColorSecondary);
  }
  li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 14px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--textColorMain);
  }
  #nav-btn {
    display: block;
    color: var(--bottonColor);
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    height: 2.5em;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
  }
  #nav-btn:hover {
    color: var(--mainColor);
    background-color: var(--bottonColor);
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: .5s;
  }
  .change {
    top: 0;
  }
  .hamburger-menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    scroll-behavior: none;
    margin-top: 2em;
    top: 1em;
    right: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    /* background-color: white; */
    align-items: flex-end;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  .nav-item {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .line {
    width: 35px;
    /* width: 100%; */
    height: 4px;
    background-color: var(--bottonColor);
    transition: all 0.8s;
  }
  .change .line-1 {
    transform: rotateZ(-405deg) translate(-8px, 6px);
  }
  .change .line-2 {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .change .line-3 {
    transform: rotateZ(405deg) translate(-8px, -6px);
  }
  /* main-cnt */
  /* 
body{
  background-image:
  linear-gradient(to right ,rgb(96,45,145),rgb(96,45,145, 0.1) ),
  url("../media/background.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;

} */
  main {
    display: block;
    padding: 9em 4em;
    height:
  }
  .main-cnt {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #bookNowBtn {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 10em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
  }
  #bookNowBtn button {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: mon semibold;
    /* float: right;; */
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgb(255, 255, 255);
  }
  #bookNowBtn button:hover {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.63);
    transition: .1s;
  }
  #mainText {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* padding-top: 7em; */
    color: white;
  }
  #mainText h2 {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 18px;
    /* line-height: 1em; */
    font-family: mon semibold;
  }
  #mainText h2 span {
    color: var(--bottonColor);
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: mon semibold;
  }
  #mainText p {
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 1em;
  }
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="nav  navbar">
            <div class="hamburger-menu">
                <div class="line line-1"></div>
                <div class="line line-2"></div>
                <div class="line line-3"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="sdlLogo" ">
                <a href="/"> <img src="sdl_logo.svg" alt="sdl_logo" height="75px " width="150px "></a>
            </div>
            <div class="right ">
                <ul>
                    <li class="nav-item active "><a href="/ ">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item "><a href="about.php ">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item "><a href="service.php ">Services</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item "><a href="article.php ">Articles</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div>
                    <a href="contact.php "> <button class="btn " id="nav-btn ">Contact Us</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<!-- main -->
<main>
    <div id="mainText " class="main-cnt ">
        <h2>
            Spectrum <span>Diagnostic</span> Laboratories
        </h2>
        <p>
            Quality results for Quality patient care.
        </p>
    </div>
    <a href="service.php#Mailing " id="bookNowBtn " class="main-cnt ">
      <button class="btn " type="submit ">Book Now!</button>
    </a>
</main>
```

Comment: That's … a *lot* of code. Please see [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Make use of the live demo tool in the question editor … which has a handy "Format my code" button that should make it more readable.

Comment: You have additional double quote after `class="sdlLogo"`.

Comment: @Nik What's with your edit suggestion? Are you trying to answer by editing the question? Don't do that; instead, copy the snippets to an answer.

Comment: @trippleee nope. i did not answer the question by editing it. just moved the code to snippet in order to see it in action. and while doing so i found the additional quote. so informed.

Comment: Also check your HTML, don't have a `<button>` inside an `<a>` tag. This doesn't make sense. Either you link somewhere or you have a button you want to click.

Comment: @Nik sometimes an additional double quote will make a mess with the project, so as tripleee said if there is a solution or suggestion it must be within a new answer or a comment.

Comment: @Nik could you please go ahead view that site i provided  above maybe you mighty find me that, bug been stack at it for days  now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the site that you have provided, There is container class in media query that has the `height: 100vh;` property, which is causing this issue.

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    /* background:wheat; */
  }
```

Either remove that class from media query or change to

```
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

This will solve your problem.